# How to record the selenium RC scripts due to security alerts in all browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

How to record scripts in Selenium RC? As of now, it throws security alerts at me (Trusted certificates), I'm so unable to record it. Please help me, how can we overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1. Start the rc with **-trustAllSSLCertificates** parameters.Your startup command should look like

   java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates
2. You should create a firefox profile as mentioned [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles). Be sure to note down the path where the profile is being created. Then open firefox in that profile (refer the same mozilla support page if you don't how to open FF in a profile) and browse your application. You will have then be prompted to accept certificate. Accept the certificate and close the browser. Now manually open firefox using the newly created profile and access the application one more time. It should not show the certificate error now. All you need to do now is to ask selenium to use this new firefoxprofile. This can be done by using the **-firefoxProfileTemplate** parameter during selenium server startup

   java -jar seleniumserver.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate="Path to firefoxprofile folder"